# How to write continuous outputs in a single txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with multiple data files (File_1, File_2, .....). I want the desired outputs for each data file to be saved in the same txt file as row values of a new column.

I tried the following code for my first data file (File_1). The desired outputs (Av_Age_btwn_0_to_5, Av_Age_btwn_5_to_10) are stored as row values of a column in the output txt file (Result.txt). Now, I want these outputs to be stored as row values of a next column of the same txt file when I work with File_2. Then for File_3, in a similar manner, I want the outputs in the next column and so on.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/File_1.txt')
Age=data[:,0]
Age_btwn_0_to_5=Age[(Age<5) & (Age>0)]
Age_btwn_5_to_10=Age[(Age<10) & (Age>=5)]
Av_Age_btwn_0_to_5=np.mean(Age_btwn_0_to_5)
Av_Age_btwn_5_to_10=np.mean(Age_btwn_5_to_10)
np.savetxt('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Result.txt', (Av_Age_btwn_0_to_5, Av_Age_btwn_5_to_10), delimiter=',')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you may either store in columns instead of rows and at the end, just enlist all lines and transpose them in vertical way., in the file.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each of your files is a column, and you want to combine them into a matrix (one file per column).

Maybe something like this could work?

```
import numpy as np

# Simulate some dummy data
def simulate_data(n_files):
    for i in range(n_files):
        ages = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
        np.savetxt("/tmp/File_{}.txt".format(i),ages,fmt='%i')

# Your file processing
def process(age):

    age_btwn_0_to_5=age[(age<5) & (age>0)]
    age_btwn_5_to_10=age[(age<10) & (age>=5)]

    av_age_btwn_0_to_5=np.mean(age_btwn_0_to_5)
    av_age_btwn_5_to_10=np.mean(age_btwn_5_to_10)

    return (av_age_btwn_0_to_5, av_age_btwn_5_to_10)

n_files = 5
simulate_data(n_files)

results = []
for i in range(n_files):
    # load data
    data=np.loadtxt('/tmp/File_{}.txt'.format(i))

    # Process your file and extract your information
    data_processed = process(data)

    # Store the result
    results.append(data_processed)

results = np.asarray(results)
np.savetxt('/tmp/Result.txt',results.T,delimiter=',',fmt='%.3f')
```

In the end, you have something like that:

```
2.649,2.867,2.270,2.475,2.632
7.080,6.920,7.288,7.231,6.880
```

Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

# some data
age = np.arange(10)
time = np.arange(10)
mean = np.arange(10)

output = np.array(list(zip(age,time,mean)))

np.savetxt('FooFile.txt', output, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
#                                                ^^^^^^^^ --> Use this keyword argument if you want to save it as int. For simplicity just don't use it.
```

output:

```sh
0,0,0
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
5,5,5
6,6,6
7,7,7
8,8,8
9,9,9
```